# Can I use "Entschuldigung für die Verspätung." for delay to hand in my homework?

Tags: phrase-request

My homework is due on the day before. I forgot to hand it in yesterday. I hope Mr. X will excuse me. Can I say

> Entschuldigung für die Verspätung.

Comment: Ultimately, yes you can except that you should say "Entschuldigen Sie" when addressing your teacher.  But you should add a little more content and tell us what's the reason you think this sentence could be wrong.

Comment: So... did Mr X excuse you after all?

Answer (score 6):

The complete and most commonly used sentence would be

> Bitte entschuldigen Sie, dass ich meine Hausaufgaben erst heute abgebe.

Usually you would give a reason, too.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with it. But this sounds more that you are late, not the hand in of your homework.

You could improve it by using a pronoun, which makes it more personal while talking to your teacher. Furthermore you could add a subject to describe what exactly is late.

> Entschuldigen Sie bitte die verspätete Abgabe meiner Hausaufgabe/n.

Comment: Mit so vielen Substantiven klingt das nach Formaldeutsch, nicht nach etwas, was ich im Alltag benutzen würde.

Comment: @Robert Stimmt schon. Jetzt stellt sich mir die Frage, ob im Rahmen dieser Seite formales Deutsch oder Umgangssprache der bessere Vorschlag ist.

Comment: Ich denke im Umgang mit Lehrpersonal ist das eine völlig akzeptable Formulierung; nur wird sie von Schülern nie verwendet ;)

Comment: Steve: Das muss Fio entscheiden. Ich hatte angenommen, dass Fio dem Lehrer sagen will, dass seine Arbeit verspätet ist. "Lehrer" und "sagen" waren da für mich ausschlaggebend, das eher informell zu machen.

Comment: Wir sollten hier auf jeden Fall immer zunächst die korrekte (und formelle) Formulierung angeben. Zusätzliche umgangssprachliche, regionale oder saloppe Formulierungen sollten als solche gekennzeichnet werden. Ausnahmen bestehen natürlich, wenn ausdrücklich nach einer umgangssprachlichen Formulierung gefragt wird.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested phrase means "sorry for the delay" which is fine but there's a more polite solution:

> Bitte entschuldigen Sie die Verspätung.

which means "please excuse the delay". "Für die verspätete Abgabe der Hausaufgabe/n" / "for handing in the homework" is implied and would be superfluous and silly to include.

- You can add a reason but some people react badly to excuses (*Ausreden*).
- Some people like to hear promises of improvement (*Es wird nicht mehr vorkommen*) but if it happens again and they remember, they will feel cheated.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much, yeah. Maybe with a little explanation why you forgot it. But a simple

> Entschuldigung für die Verspätung.

should do.

Comment: Which still sounds like *you* are late for class, not that you're handing in your homework late.

Comment: If you enter the room, yes. But if you hand over the homework? Its about the context.

Comment: I don't know if you're a native speaker, but when you think back to your school days, would you have used your sentence when handing in your homework late?

Comment: Yes, thats why I post it. I'm not a very formal guy and I often keep me short. Perhaps I should have mentioned, that this is very informal and the meaning is based on the context. Thanks for your criticism.

Answer (score 0):

> Entschuldigung für die Verspätung.

seems okay to me.

Alternatively

> Entschuldigung für die verspätete Abgabe [meiner Hausaufgaben].